# In DQN, when do the parameters in the Neural Network update based on the reward received?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, deep-learning, dqn

I'm aware that we back-propagate after computing the loss between:

The Neural Network Q values and the Target Network Q values

However, all this is doing is updating the parameters of the Neural Network to produce an output that matches the Target Q values as close as possible.

Suppose one epoch is run and the reward is +10, surely we need to update the parameters using this too to tell the Network to push the probability of these actions, given these parameters up.

How does the algorithm know +10 is good? Suppose the reward range is -10 for loss and +10 for win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, all this is doing is updating the parameters of the Neural Network to produce an output that matches the Target Q values as close as possible.

Yes. That is all it needs to do because we have defined the policy around the Q values like so:

$$\pi(s) = \text{argmax}_a \hat{q}(s,a,\theta)$$

Where $\theta$ is the neural network weights.

Therefore, if the estimates of Q are approximately the same as the action value of the optimal policy, the policy in DQN is approximately the optimal policy.

> How does the algorithm know +10 is good?

It does not, at least not directly. The algorithm knows, approximately, what the action values are **if** it acts consistently with their current estimates by always choosing the maximising action at each step.

The learning process will learn that +10 is *relatively* good in your scenario because it never finds anything better when exploring.